# is $1^z=1$ for all complex values of $z$?

Tags: complex-numbers

i would like to see if   $1^z=1$   is valid for all complex variable  $z$,first of all  you can rewrite above  equation as

$1^{a+b*i}=e^0$
here i think that instead of $+$ sign, we may take  take complex conjugate  form or $-$ sign.from above equation  we can  get

$1^a *1^{b*i}=e^0$

or  $1^{b*i}=1$

here i am assuming that  $a$  is real,otherwise  if we  have complex variable in power  complex variable,result will be undefined,so now question is:  could you conclude that

$1^{b*i}=1$?

generally  i  know that $i^0=1$

so

$i^{0*b*i}=1$

we get identity ,but is this right?

i would like to show you following article
http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/complex.shtml

with title :
Complex number to a complex power may be real

what could i say above equation?
also  we  may introduce  some useful well known  identities,but which one could be  relevant for this  case?thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the particular branch of the complex logarithm you choose, for example:

$$1^i=e^{i\operatorname{Log}1}=e^{i\log|1|-\arg 1}=e^{-\arg 1}\in\{e^0=1\;,\;e^{-2\pi}\;,\;e^{2\pi}\;,\;e^{-2\pi}\,,\ldots\}$$

Comment: so one necessary  condition for  equation hold  is that  in $z=a+b*i$ ,   $b=0$? or  complex number contains only  real part?

Comment: Well, in this case it is necessary *and sufficient*, as you can see. I can't understand your question "or complex number contains only real part?"

Comment: sorry i should ask it to Three,wrong place,sorry.i have understood it,just when he said  unless $b=0$,i have asked about it.when  imaginary part is zero,clearly  complex number contains only real part i meant this.thanks

Comment: i have one question @DonAntonio,what is  arg1 stand for?is  it just  some number or argument of complex number?

Comment: argument, @dato

Answer (score 1):

$ 1^{ib}=({e^{2\pi i }})^{ib}= e^{-2\pi b}\neq1  $, unless $ b = 0$

Here, I've used the fact that $e^{2\pi i} = 1 $ and $ i^2 = -1$

Comment: Here, for example, Three chose the branch of the complex logarithm for which $\,\arg(1)=2\pi\,$ ...